# How can you say "Looking forward to hearing from you soon"?

Tags: questions, correspondance

Google translates it as

> J'attends avec impatience d'avoir de tes nouvelles.

I think it's a good translation, but I'm not completely  sure.

Comment: For once google translate is not too bad, but could do better. Better than google translate, a [proper online dictionary](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/looking%20forward%20to%20hearing).

Comment: @Laure Thank you! I will certainly use it!

Comment: Choosing between one or the other depends who you are addressing. So If you give more context in your question we can give you a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" Soon " pourrait être traduit littéralement (et surtout avec mesure), par exemple : 
- j'espère avoir bientôt de tes nouvelles ;
- j'attends de tes nouvelles bientôt [certes, la construction est tirée par les cheveux mais très usitée].
Le degré d'impatience me paraît exageré dans " j'ai hâte ", " avec impatience ", etc. Il faudrait connaître le contexte.

Comment: Just wanted to learn some ways of saying that, either formal or informal. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

That's right. You could shorten it a little bit:

> Je suis impatient d'avoir de tes nouvelles.

Or make it more informal with `avoir hâte de` (hâte = haste)

> J'ai hâte d'avoir de tes nouvelles.

Or even make it more romantic with `se languir`

> Je me languis d'avoir de tes nouvelles.

Comment: "J'ai hâte de...  » is a lot **more formal**  than « Je suis impatient.. »

Comment: And yet i think that *J'ai hâte de* is more used in everyday speech. Maybe because it's shorter? What would be the everyday-speech version otherwise?

Comment: It is context dependent, "être impatient" is probably the more neutral.  In some  parts of France "il me tarde de.. " would be the usual thing to say and "j'ai hâte..." considered really elaborate.